# Read JSON file and Pretty-Print it to another file

Tags: python, json

I have a complex (nested) json text file that is one long line in the text file

Is there any way to read in the file (in python) and indent / pretty-print the json to a new text file?

Comment: Where is your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file using `json.load(..)`, and use `json.dump(..)` to write the object out to another file while specifying indent value.

```
with open("inFile") as f, open("outFile", "w") as g:
    json.dump(json.load(f), g, indent=4)
```

Comment: This appears to work somewhat, but it loads the json to the outfile in a different order than the infile for some reason.

Comment: The order of unordered items like key-value pairs in an object will not be preserved. And if you have to care about this order, you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, I'm not the one using the JSON.  Anyway, a more important problem seems to have arisen.  The first section of my JSON appears to have been deleted in the outfile.  This can't be normal.  hmm.

Comment: Only way we can help you is if you [update your question with an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with current and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) to read/write file, then [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) to read the file and [`json.dump(..., indent=4)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) to pretty-print it.